# insertion sort in python not working

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I have tried the following code for insertion sort in python

```
a=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    temp=a[i]
    for k in range (i,1,-1):
        a[k]=a[k-1]
        if a[k]<temp:
            a[k]=temp
            break
print(a)
```

input: 6 4 3 2 5 8 1

output: [6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8]

Comment: as per the wiki page http://pastebin.com/2tx2bcFT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I guess your question has been downvoted because your question does not show a lot of research effort. This is a very common problem and a quick Google search should give you a lot of results. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *does not work* because your implementation is faulty.
When trying to shift the partially sorted list, you overwrite existing numbers by assigning `a[k] = a[k-1]` -- but where's the former value of `a[k]` then?

A very basic solution (yet not in-place as the original definition on a single list is defined) could look like this.

```
inp = '1 4 6 3 1 6 3 5 8 1'

# 'a' is the input list
a = [int(x) for x in inp.split()]
# 'r' is the sorted list
r = []
# In the original descriptions, insertion sort operates
# on a single list while iterating over it. However, this
# may lead to major failurs, thus you better carry the
# sorted list in a separate variable if memory is not
# a limiting factor (which it can hardly be for lists that
# are typed in by the user).

for e in a:
    if not len(r):
        # The first item is the inialization
        r.append(e)
    else:
        # For each subsequent item, find the spot in 'r'
        # where it has to go.
        idx = 0
        while idx < len(r) and r[idx] < e: idx += 1
        # We are lazy and use insert() instead of manually
        # extending the list by 1 place and copying over
        # all subsequent items [idx:] to the right
        r.insert(idx, e)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after iterating over the sequence starting from index 1 till the length of the loop we need to use a while loop, because we need to iterate over the sequence multiple times.

The following code will do the job.

```
import sys
def insertionsort(A):
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        pos = A[i]
        j = i-1
        while j >= 0 and pos < A[j]:
            A[j+1] = A[j]
            j -= 1
        A[j+1] = pos


A = [55, 45, 2, 9, 75, 64]
insertionsort(A)
print(A)
```